# How to disable history in spring activiti

Tags: spring, spring-boot, activiti

I am using Activiti with spring boot, I am facing few performance issues while getting the data from the activiti tables this is due to the history tables I guess.

When I am querying for the data from the activiti tables, in the 1st scenario it took 0.239 seconds to get the result but in the 2nd scenario it took 1.884 seconds to fetch the data from the database.

[image]

This is the main reason, I want to disable the history.

Tech stack:

Spring Activiti - 5.22.0

Spring Boot version - 1.5.8.Release

MyBatis for ORM

Please let me know, Is there any configuration to disable the history and will be there any problems if we disable the history.

Answer (score 2):

You can disable history by setting history attribute of ProcessEngineConfiguration in your @Configuration class.

```
@Configuration
public class ActivityConfig {

    @Autowired
    DataSource dataSource;

    @Bean
    public DataSourceTransactionManager getTransactionManager() {
        return new DataSourceTransactionManager(dataSource);
    }

    @Bean
    public ProcessEngineConfigurationImpl getProcessEngineConfiguration() {
        SpringProcessEngineConfiguration res = new SpringProcessEngineConfiguration();
        res.setDataSource(dataSource);
        res.setHistory("full");
        res.setTransactionManager(getTransactionManager());
        return res;
    }

    @Bean
    public ProcessEngineFactoryBean getProcessEngine() {
        ProcessEngineFactoryBean res = new ProcessEngineFactoryBean();
        res.setProcessEngineConfiguration(getProcessEngineConfiguration());
        return res;
    }

    @Bean
    public RepositoryService getRepositoryService() throws Exception {
        return getProcessEngine().getObject().getRepositoryService();
    }

    @Bean
    public FormService getFormService() throws Exception {
        return getProcessEngine().getObject().getFormService();
    }

    @Bean
    public TaskService getTaskService() throws Exception {
        return getProcessEngine().getObject().getTaskService();
    }

    @Bean
    public RuntimeService getRuntimeService() throws Exception {
        return getProcessEngine().getObject().getRuntimeService();
    }

    @Bean
    public HistoryService getHistoryService() throws Exception {
        return getProcessEngine().getObject().getHistoryService();
    }

    @Bean
    public IdentityService getIdentityService() throws Exception {
        return getProcessEngine().getObject().getIdentityService();
    }
}
```

If you set the history to NONE you will have no problem but also no informations about the past activities.

The levels you can set are : NONE, ACTIVITY, AUDIT, FULL.
Here are the details : https://www.activiti.org/5.x/userguide/#historyConfig

Comment: I tried as you said, I pasted below code in springboot configuration class.
eg: @Bean
 public ProcessEngineConfigurationImpl getProcessEngineConfiguration() {
        SpringProcessEngineConfiguration processEngineConf = new SpringProcessEngineConfiguration();
        processEngineConf.setHistory(HistoryLevel.NONE.getKey());
        return processEngineConf;
 }

But still I couldn't able to stop the history into the tables. Is there anything which I can modify.

Comment: could you post the whole Configuration class ?

Comment: I edited my post and added my whole configuration class

Comment: Thanks for your help. Actually I fixed this in different way. Somehow it is not taking the history when I am adding that in the configuration class. So when I am starting the process, there I am declaring the history level. This worked for me. Really your answer helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at here : https://github.com/Activiti/Activiti/blob/5.x/modules/activiti-spring-boot/spring-boot-starters/activiti-spring-boot-starter-basic/src/main/java/org/activiti/spring/boot/ActivitiProperties.java#L46

You can try :

```
spring.activiti.historyLevel=none
```

In your application.properties file.
Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm not using activiti with Spring Boot, nevertheless setting that parameter in activiti.cfg.xml unfortunately is not enough

Answer (score 0):

We can stop the history by keeping the history level as "NONE". But the main point here is where to set the history level. Using @e.g78 idea I updated the code in the configuration level, but that didn't fix my problem. So I updated my code as below.

```
@Autowired
private SpringProcessEngineConfiguration config;

@GetMapping("/startProcess")
public String startProcess() {
    config.setHistoryLevel(HistoryLevel.NONE);
    RuntimeService runtimeService = config.getRuntimeService();
    runtimeService.startProcessInstanceByKey("testing_DeletingHistory", "start");
```

Thanks e.g78. Your answer helped me, with few modifications.